# different java version between java_home and popen

Tags: java, python, pycharm

In python IDE, i run these two code snippets and get different output for the java version:

```
stdout,stderr = Popen(['java','-version'], shell=False,   stderr=PIPE).communicate()
print(stderr)
```

> java version "1.7.0"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pwi3270sr8fp10-20141219_01(SR8 FP10))
>   IBM J9 VM (build 2.6, JRE 1.7.0 Windows 7 x86-32 20141216_227497 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
>   J9VM - R26_Java726_SR8_20141216_0955_B227497
>   JIT  - r11.b07_20141003_74578.05
>   GC   - R26_Java726_SR8_20141216_0955_B227497
>   J9CL - 20141216_227497)
>   JCL - 20141217_01 based on Oracle jdk7u75-b12

```
os.system("java -version")
```

> java version "1.8.0_40"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b26)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)

Why do i get a different java version inside my python IDE (PyCharm)? How can i change it?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because `os.system()` uses the shell (so will pick up any changes in .bashrc / .profile etc... Are you setting a different Java location in your `$PATH` / `$JAVA_HOME` in any of those?

I believe `Popen` doesn't invoke a shell (unless you set `shell=true`).

Disclaimer: Not tested this.

Comment: I have C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin\java.exe in $PATH and $JAVA_HOME , and i don't change it anywhere.